# Where to put a .txt file if I want to read it out from the integrated Simulator in Vivado?

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado

I have a text-file I want to read in inside my simulation.vhd file but I do not know where to put it so that the code finds it, since I am not quite sure where it gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simulator executes in the .sim folder - but this folder gets reset everytime when you start the simulation. Therefore the .txt file must be outside the sim folder and the the simulation.vhd you need to give a full path to the file like this:

```
   stimuli : process                                                                             
   file infile: text open read_mode is "C:\Users\Name\F\L\lena_sw.txt";
```

Comment: You may consider using a relative path, like "..\Name\F\L\lena_sw.txt", or whatever is suitable, so the design can be moved or you can have multiple design residing in parallel.